# Login failed for user 'SQL Login'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided [ SERVER IP] 18456

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Recently I have Installed a New server as a up-gradation for an Application. I require both servers running as Different applications need to be run.

I have updated the IP of old server to new One & assigned another IP for Old server.

Example :

- OLD IP : 115.19.1.4 ( This assigned now to new one)
- New IP : 115.19.1.7 (This is new IP for OLD server)

but I'm facing a issue that the SQL Login of OLD server is still hitting the new server IP 115.19.1.4 and in event manager it is showing in events as below:

> Login failed for user 'SQL Login'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided [ SERVER IP] 18456

Comment: If both instances are on the same server, you need to disable IPALL for both instances in SQL Server Configuration Manager if you want each instance to listen on a single IP.

Answer (score 0):

The user name in the message is not a user. This means the server itself is trying to login to SQL Server.

means <115.19.1.7\YourSqlServerName>